# Order : To add comments programmatically for an order in admin panel in magento 2

Tags: php, sales-order, magento2.2

In admin panel Sales->Orders section, while viewing the order, It show order information like below,How to add comment programatically.... And it needs to save (sale_order_status_history) table  Suggest a solution..
[image]

Comment: have you checked?

Comment: `addStatusHistoryComment` is deprecated, use `addCommentToStatusHistory` instead. Check my answer for more details: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/330219/35758

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$orderId = $orderId;
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('This comment is programatically added to last order in this Magento setup');
    $order->save();
```

you can also user magento repo object as well.

Comment: how to pass same comment dynamically

Comment: See \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::addCommentToStatusHistory() because "addStatusHistoryComment" is deprecated already

Answer (score 7):

`addStatusHistoryComment` is deprecated, use `addCommentToStatusHistory` instead.

**Here is the sample code:**

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderRepository $orderRepository
    ...
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function saveOrder($orderId)
{
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
    $order->addCommentToStatusHistory('Test Order Comment');
    $this->orderRepository->save($order);
}
```

Check for more details: `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::addCommentToStatusHistory`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this code.Please create a sample file in the root and paste below code.and run this file.

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('./app/bootstrap.php');
$mage_bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$object_Manager = $mage_bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$site_url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $site_url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaurl= $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
$state = $object_Manager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$orderId = 15;

$order = $object_Manager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId); 
$order->addStatusToHistory('pending', 'Put your comment here', false);
$order->save();
```

Once you run this file you can see the updated status from the admin.
Thanks!!!